# C++ Output: GUI or Console?

Tags: c++

I am making an application in C++ that runs a simulation for a health club. The user simply enters the simulation data at the beginning (3 integer values) and presses run. After that there is no user input - so very simple.

After starting the simulation a lot of the logic is deep down in lower classes but a lot of them need to print simple output messages to the UI. Returning a message is not possible as objects need to print to the UI but keep working.

I was going to pass a reference to the UI object to all classes that need it but I end up passing it around quite a lot - there must be a better way.

**What I really need is something that can make calling the UI's printOutput(string) function as easy (or not much more difficult) than cout << string;**

The UI also has a displayConnectionStatus(bool[] connections) method.

Bear in mind the UI inherits an abstract 'UserInterface' class so simple console UIs and GUIs can be changed in and out easily.

How do you suggest I implement this link to the UI?

If I were to use a global function, how can I redirect it to call methods of the UserInterface implementation that I selected to use?

Comment: Global singleton? (That's effectively what cout is in your desired usage.)

Comment: have you considered using a logging framework (log4cpp for example)

Comment: @ David Hope I've never heard of it.

Comment: @metal Aren't singletons 'global' by default? You can get the object by calling the static getInstance() method which can be called from anywhere.

Comment: Only if you can see the object. It could be a private, nested class inside another class, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

Don't be afraid of globals.

Global objects hurt encapsulation, but for a targeted solution with no concern for immediate reusability, globals are just fine.

Expose a global object that processes events from your simulation. You can then choose to print the events, send them by e-mail, render them with OpenGL or whatever you fancy. Make a uniform interface that catches what happens inside the simulation via report callbacks, and then you can subclass this global object to suit your needs.

If the object wasn't global, you'd be passing a pointer around all the codebase.

Comment: I pressed 'edit' rather than 'comment' first time round - been a long day. Anyway, what I was going to say - Yes I would have had to pass the pointer around which would have been annoying, but everyone seems to keep saying that globals are bad :S

Comment: People like absolute truths. Rules are easier than careful evaluation, since they are almost always good to heed. However, they are not universal. There are perfectly good reasons to use global objects -- hell, there are even legitimate uses of `goto` (the Linux kernel uses it extensively) and everyone will tell you `goto` is PLAIN EVIL (tm).

Comment: Maintaining globals some time become a real issue, and especially in multi-threaded env we face issues which are very difficult to identify, in past i had to work with a project which extensively was using globals in it was just pain in ass to get rid of weird behavior due to those, so i personally think we should go for global only if there is no other solution...

Comment: Close your ears. This guy is a rebel unleashed )

Comment: You can see why choosing a global/non-global solution is so difficult lol

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for logging framework i.e. your own class LogMessages, which got functions which get data and log the data, it can be to a UI, file, over network or anything.

And each class which needs logging, can use your logging class.

This way you can avoid globals and a generic solution , also have a look at http://www.pantheios.org/ which is open source C/C++ Diagnostic Logging API library, you may use that also...

Comment: I edited my question slightly. The string output method is not the only one in the UI. It also has a showConnectionStatus(bool[]) method.